# Meaning of -u and -f flag inside os.system in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, flags

I am trying to run a C executable say `c4.5` and `c4.5rules` which will take a single command line argument inside a python code using `os.system`, I am using the C executable written by some other person, and I don't have the original `.c` file with me. I need to write like below to make sure that executable file is doing okay.

```
import sys
import os
dataset = sys.argv[1]
os.system(f"/home/Dev/c4.5 -u -f {dataset}")
os.system(f"/home/Dev/c4.5rules -u -f {dataset}")
os.system(f"/home/Dev/c4.5rules -u -f {dataset} > Temp")

f = open('Temp')
...
```

And if I remove that `-u` and `-f`, then it is not working.

Why is it happening and what is the use of `-u` and `-f`?

Comment: Those are command line arguments for the `c4.5` and `c4.5rules`. Impossible to say what they do or why they are needed without seeing the source code. In your case, only the person that wrote that program can tell you that. Alternatively, you could try running these executables in your command line with a `-h`, ususally that will give you a help message explaining the command line arguments.

Comment: Okay got it. Can I use subprocess instead of os?

Comment: And how can I use that `-h` can you explain please!

Comment: Just write `/home/Dev/c4.5 -h` in your terminal